# Console redirect not working as expected

Tags: freebsd

I have a script that I want to watch run on the monitor. This is running on OPNsense, which is based on FreeBSD. The output is displayed, but each line starts as if tabbed every time. See screenshot.

Here is the script that is in the screenshot. Any ideas on how to keep the formatting?

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/vidcontrol -s 1 < /dev/ttyv0
exec > /dev/ttyv0

clear
echo
echo Starting Step 1...
echo
echo Starting Step 2...
echo
echo Starting Step 3...
```

[image: ttyv0 formatting issue]